# AngularJS - Load factory result during app launch

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have multiple controller files and in of them I am trying to load the result from a factory as soon as the controller is triggered. I am loading the user information. Currently when the page loads, it shows nothing but when I click refresh all information shows.

How can i fix this to eliminate the need for the refresh button?

This is my code in the main body of the controller:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();    

if (currentUser) {
    // do stuff with the user
    $scope.tempUserObject = UserDetails.overallDetails();
} else {
    // show the signup or login page
    $scope.logout();
}
```

Comment: You could get your factory current function to return a promise and then process accordingly in your controllers

Comment: This is to defer the load you mean until the result is returned by the factory?

Comment: Yes looks like someone has stole my thunder though...

Comment: put your thunder as an answer and lets see

Comment: Lol, hardly seems worth it now :)

Answer (score 0):

you return only promise from Factory. e.g.:

**Controller**

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();    

if (currentUser) {
    // do stuff with the user
    $scope.tempUserObject = UserDetails.overallDetails().success(function(response){
      console.log(response);
   }).error(function(error){
      console.log("Error = "+error);
   });
} else {
    // show the signup or login page
    $scope.logout();
}
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory('UserDetails', ['$http', function($http){
return {
    overallDetails : overallDetailsFun
 }

function overallDetailsFun(){

  return {
          $http.get("127.0.0.1/api/details");
      }
 }
}]);
```